# Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds when to security:check in symfony

Tags: symfony

It is my first installation according to http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html.
Here is the history commands on my console.

```
curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
symfony -v
Symfony Installer (1.5.0)
cd my_project_name/
php app/console server:run
#php bin/console server:run  it is wrong in the material
#for my version it is php app/console server:run
```

Everything is in good status until now.

```
 php app/console security:check

An error occurred: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received.
```

What result in it?How to fix it?

Comment: Add some related code also for better understanding.

Comment: if its an enormous application, you might need to up the script execution max in php.ini (cli)

Answer (score 3):

I found this page after having the same issue (well, mine timed out after 10001 seconds ;-)). Not finding any good indicators, I decided to have a look at the security:check command, and found it posts your `composer.lock` file to https://security.sensiolabs.org for analysis. The curl timeout for this request is set to 10 seconds, which matches the 10000 milliseconds. I tried to access security.sensiolabs.org from my browser and found it was not responding.

So, there's the cause. The Sensiolabs web service that checks your project dependencies for known vulnerabilities is likely having issues (I'm pretty sure it's not a firewall issue since that would immediately deny the request instead of timing out). You'll have to wait this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [SensioLabs Security Advisories Checker](https://security.sensiolabs.org/check).

`wget http://get.sensiolabs.org/security-checker.phar`

`php security-checker.phar security:check /path/to/your/composer.lock`

The output should look something like this:

```
Security Check Report ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Checked file: /var/www/www.crmpicco.co.uk/composer.lock

[OK]  0 packages have known vulnerabilities  

This checker can only detect vulnerabilities that are referenced  
Disclaimer  in the SensioLabs security advisories database. 
Execute this command regularly to check the newly discovered vulnerabilities.
```